# How to publish a specific version (not the latest) of an item?

Tags: publishing, versions

Let's assume that I have version 1, 2 and 3 of the same Sitecore item.

For test purpose only I need to publish version 2.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to manipulate with workflow state of newer versions or with publishing restrictions.

You can use Sitecore API and `PublishOptions.PublishDate` property. Just pass the datetime when your chosen version was created as the constructor argument like:

```
new PublishOptions(..., ..., version.Statistics.Created);
```

And pass it to `PublishItemContext`:

```
var options = new PublishOptions(version.Database, targetDatabase, PublishMode.Full, version.Language, version.Statistics.Created);
var context = PublishManager.CreatePublishItemContext(version.ID, options);
context.PublishContext = new PublishContext(options);
return PublishItemPipeline.Run(context);
```

I wrote a blog post which explains in details how and why it works. You can read it here:

**[Publish specific version of Sitecore item](https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/publish-specific-version-of-sitecore-item)**.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by playing with one of those two things:

- You can **set the [Publishable](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/set-up-publishing-restrictions-for-an-item.html)** option of version 3 to **false**.
- If you have workflow configured in this item, you or the author can set the version 3 **back to the *draft* state**.